# Check if graph is multigraph given degree sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, multigraphs

I am given some **degree sequences** of graphs, and my question is what is the method to determine which of them are sequences corresponding to **multigraphs**.

1. 1,2,2,3
2. 0,1,2,3
3. 2,2,2,2

Comment: Any simple graph can also be interpreted as a multigraph.  There are some multigraphs who can be interpreted as a simple graph and others who may not.  There are some degree sequences which can be used by simple graphs (*and thus also multigraphs*).  There are some degree sequences which can be used by simple graphs as well as used by multigraphs who are not simple.  There are some degree sequences which can only be used by multigraphs and can not be used by simple graphs.  There are some degree sequences which cannot be used by any graph, simple or otherwise.

Comment: Your examples you have here, it should be easy to come up with examples of simple graphs (*as well as non-simple*) for the first and third.  As for the second it should be clear that if there was a degree-3 vertex in a simple graph that we would have needed it to be adjacent to the degree-0 vertex which is impossible.

Comment: You want the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) and the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem)

Answer (score -2):

They're all realizable for multigraphs; with 4 vertices, you can just try by hand:

[image]

We also see that $(1,2,2,3)$ and $(2,2,2,2)$ are realizable for simple graphs.

However, the sequence $(3,2,1,0)$ is not realizable for simple graphs: the vertex of degree 3 needs to attach to 3 other vertices, but there are only 3 other vertices and one has degree 0 (i.e., no edges).